# Mock java.io.File with an in-memory FileSystem. Maybe JimFs

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using a third party library that works with `java.io.File` instances. I'd like to use this library in my unit tests but I don't want it to create files on disk.

My first idea was to use [JimFs](https://github.com/google/jimfs) to mock the file system but it does not support java.io.File.

My second idea was to mock File with some mocking framework and delegate calls to JimFs but don't know if that will work.

Is there some solution out there to use virtual java.io.File?

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: @nafas osx:) but was hoping for a OS independent solution

Comment: May be you could write a temp file ?

Comment: Will the Path.toFile() not work?

Comment: Why don't you want the files to be created on disk?

Comment: @Duncan I want the tests to be fast and not pollute my disk. I just don't need them on the disk for anything so why create them.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking Path.toFile won't work, they don't support it in JimFs

Comment: @metrimer if you were going to use linux, then task would be much more simpler, as you could write into /tmp folder :).

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking ```toFile()``` is implemented with ```throw new UnsupportedOperationException();``` https://github.com/google/jimfs/blob/master/jimfs/src/main/java/com/google/common/jimfs/JimfsPath.java#L409

Answer (score 2):

You could use a JUnit [`TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule to easily create temporary files that are deleted after the test method is complete.